# VB.net Upload Folder content using listbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, listbox

Hello i am currently making program that can upload files to ftp. I want to transfer all files from "Files" folder to my FTP server i have the code and everything and list box that lists all the file names with extensions to an list. But i cannot figure out how to actually make it work. Here is my code:

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim myFTPaddress As String = "ftp://127.0.0.1/"
        Dim myFTPuserName As String = "root"
        Dim myFTPuserPassword As String = ""
        Dim myFiles() As String = {TextBox1.Text + "Files\" + ListBox1.Text} '// files for testing.
        Dim sTemp As String = Nothing '// used to extract only FileName with Extenstion.
        For Each mySelectedFile As String In myFiles '// loop thru your files.
            sTemp = IO.Path.GetFileName(mySelectedFile) '// get only the file name with extension from Full Path.
            '// upload File to website.
            My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(mySelectedFile, myFTPaddress & sTemp, myFTPuserName, myFTPuserPassword)
        Next
        MsgBox("File(s) Upload Successful.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Sub
```

Comment: `GetFileName` wont fill in the full path if it is not there. `myFiles()` is an array but you dont put any files in it.  Set a *breakpoint* and *watch* the results in *debug*

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is there an issue with the code you provided or are you trying to modify this code so it uploads all files in a folder, or from a listbox, or something. Please rephrase the question so it is clearer.

Comment: I have listbox with filenames for example "test.png" and below is "test2.png" but when i run the program it tells me that UploadFile needs to include a file name and i think its happening cause there is 2 items in the listbox and it cannot run them separetly

Comment: And sorry for my English i am from Finland and i am very tired now. And i want to edit my last comment by saying that i mean upload instead of run.